# Rubygems can't find sinatra directly after install

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I can't figure out why rubygems is unable to find sinatra on the **require "sinatra"** line in the following code. I've tried to write the ruby to ensure that sinatra is installed..

Ruby

```
$:.push("/home/xxxx/ruby/gems")
require 'rubygems'

begin
  gem "sinatra"
rescue LoadError
  system("gem install sinatra")
  Gem.clear_paths
end

require 'sinatra'

get "/" do
 "Hello, world!"
end
```

Error - on line: require 'sinatra'

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sinatra (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

I'm running the script through SSH with the bash command 'ruby app.rb', if that's relevant.

Gem env returns: (where /home/xxxx/ruby/gems is the correct location of the gems)

```
    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.25
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/xxxx/ruby/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/xxxx/ruby/gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/xxxx/ruby/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gempath" => []
     - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
     - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
     - "gemhome" => "/home/xxxx/ruby/gems"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: If you're installing the gem from a ruby script, you may be installing it in a different folder. You should check `/home/xxxx/ruby/gems` to see if it's actually there.

Comment: There was an install in this folder `/home/xxxx/ruby/gems/gems/sinatra-1.4.5` But I just uninstalled it and the script isn't replacing it.. I think you're right. Surely the `$:.push("/home/xxxx/ruby/gems")` is setting the gems folder?? Any tips? Thanks

Comment: Try running `gem install sinatra` from the command line, then run a sample ruby script that only requires sinatra, and does a simple `get`.

Comment: Just tried, with the script: 
`$:.push("/home/xxxx/ruby/gems") 
require 'rubygems' 
require 'sinatra'` 
and I get the same error.

Comment: Are you using bundler?

Comment: No. It's not installed either

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using bundler.

First, `gem install bundler` on both your dev machine and on the server.

Next create a file named *Gemfile* which contains something like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra"
# add a "gem" line for any other gems your application needs
```

(The command `bundle init` will create a skeleton Gemfile for you).

Then you do a "bundle install" to install the gems.  This will create a "Gemfile.lock" file which gives the exact version of each gem.  That file gets checked into your version control along with the Gemfile.

Once that code has been distributed to the server, then "bundle install" on the server to get the exact same gems installed there.

In your application, do *not*:

- require "rubygems"
- Modify $:
- Install missing gems

On the server where you want to run your application, instead of just `ruby app`, you will run `bundle exec ruby app`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure this is a really stupid question, but what do you call the gemfile? 'gemfile'? 'gemfile.rb'?

Comment: I've followed your guide and `bundle install` says `Could not find bundler` and lists gems that aren't in my gem folder. However `gem query --local` returns the correct list of gems. Is `bundle` somehow pointing to a different install? (I'm not in full control of the server)

Comment: @Ian The bundler gem needs to be installed; I've edited the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I had already guessed that and installed bundler with your method, and still get these errors. I'm really struggling to understand what's going on here. As I'm using bash through ssh I'm having to declare aliases for each gem, linking them to the files in `/home/xxxx/ruby/gems/bin/`. Could that be the source of problems?

Comment: @Ian I think you're right.  Unfortunately, I don't have any knowledge that can help you there--I've never had such restricted access to a server.

Comment: I've found a solution..! as I was using SSH, I needed to add this line to my .bash_profile: `export GEM_PATH=/home/xxxx/ruby/gems/:${GEM_PATH}` Thanks for the pointers, you definitely helped

Comment: @Ian Outstanding!  You might consider adding that as an answer and giving it the checkmark.  Then someone else with the same symptoms can quickly see how you solved the problem.